# Where did the AT-M6s and AT-ATs come from?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, first-order

During the climax of *The Last Jedi*, the First Order

> sends down a battalion of AT-M6s and and AT-ATs to the surface of Crait.

Where did these walkers come from? Were they on one of the ships

> damaged by Holdo's sacrifice?

If so, how did they deliver their cargo?

Comment: They mined the metal from the planet's surface, then refined, smelted, forged, and assembled them right there in front of the cave.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Snoke's command ship is truly enormous. It's hundreds of times larger than a Star Destroyer and even with a great big chunk taken out of it, vast sections of the ship appear to be completely undamaged.

Kylo Ren orders Hux to gather his forces and take them down to the planet. It seems highly likely that they came from somewhere in the sections that weren't directly impacted. The [Incredible Cross-Sections](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Incredible_Cross-Sections) factbook identifies #1 as being a

> Vehicle Manufactury

and #2 as being a

> Military Staging Area

Either would be good candidates for sending troops and mechanised transports down to the surface.

[image]

Comment: And we did see the battering ram cannon in the hangar when Rey's pod is being brought in through the forcefield, so that has provenance as well.

Answer (score 4):

I assumed that they came from

> Snoke's ship. While it was seriously damaged, most of it was in the right "wing". That left a LOT of ship undamaged.

There's a couple of things to bolster my theory

> 1. We see AT-STs in the hangar bay where Finn and Rose have been taken (which looks to be pretty large). It's safe to assume a ship that large held all the equipment we saw.
> 2. We see Kylo Ren's personal shuttle (which is distinctive) accompanying the M6s. Since Kylo Ren was on Snoke's ship when Holdo attacked, it's probable that that particular shuttle was in a bay on the other side that was completely unharmed and fully functional. So other shuttles/transports would likely have been there to deliver them to the surface